# single output file containing multiple columns

Tags: fortran90

I was trying to code this [problem](http://dafeda.wordpress.com/2011/06/06/1d-convection-equation-using-finite-differences-in-c/) in fortran. The output file contains the result in two columns. I am having hard time to modify my code (below) to get a gnuplot-ready output file containing nt columns and nx lines. Can anybody help me? Thanks!

```
PROGRAM odlc
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER::i,it,nx,nt,k,ierr
DOUBLE PRECISION::dx,dt,c
DOUBLE PRECISION,DIMENSION(2000)::u,un
ierr=0
nx=20
nt=50
dt=0.01
c=1.0
dx=2./(nx-1.)
!initial condition
DO i = 1,nx
    IF(i*dx>=0.5 .and. i*dx<=1) THEN
    u(i) = 2    
    ELSE
    u(i)=1
    ENDIF   
ENDDO
!Finite Difference
OPEN(UNIT=200,FILE='tab2.txt',STATUS='REPLACE',ACTION='WRITE',IOSTAT=ierr)
  DO it=1,nt
    DO k=1,nx
    un(k)=u(k)
    ENDDO 
        DO i=2,nx-1
        u(i)=un(i)-c*dt/dx*(un(i)-un(i-1))
        ENDDO
            DO i=1,nx
            WRITE(200,'(I7,F10.2)')i,u(i)
            ENDDO
ENDDO
CLOSE(UNIT=200)
END
```

Comment: so the code works like you want it to, you just want the output in a different format? what do you want it to look like?

Comment: I modified my original post. Sorry for the unclear questions. I am looking for an output file having nx lines and nt columns. Many thanks! and yes the code works just fine. @bananafish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure that it is exactly what you want but here you go:

Declare

```
CHARACTER(len=32)::fmt
```

and initialize it like this

```
WRITE(fmt,*)'(',nx,'F10.2)'
```

This just creates a format string which writes a single line of `nx` reals.

Then replace

```
DO i=1,nx
WRITE(200,'(I7,F10.2)')i,u(i)
ENDDO
```

by

```
    WRITE(200,fmt) (/ (u(i), i=1,nx) /)
```

Now in your `tab2.txt` file, you will get `nt` lines and `nx` columns.

---

After your update, here is the (slightly shortened) code that will do what you want:

```
PROGRAM odlc
  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTEGER::i,it
  INTEGER,PARAMETER::nx=20,nt=50
  DOUBLE PRECISION,PARAMETER::dx=2./(nx-1.),dt=0.01,c=1.0
  DOUBLE PRECISION,DIMENSION(nt,nx)::u
  CHARACTER(len=32)::fmt
  WRITE(fmt,*)'(I3,',nt,'F5.2)'
  !initial condition                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  DO i = 1,nx
     IF(i*dx>=0.5 .and. i*dx<=1) THEN
        u(1,i) = 2
     ELSE
        u(1,i)=1
     ENDIF
  ENDDO
  !Finite Difference                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  DO it=2,nt
     DO i=2,nx-1
        u(it,i)=u(it-1,i)-c*dt/dx*(u(it-1,i)-u(it-1,i-1))
     ENDDO
  ENDDO
  !Write to file                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  OPEN(UNIT=200,FILE='tab2.txt',STATUS='REPLACE',ACTION='WRITE')
  DO i=1,nx
     WRITE(200,fmt)REAL(i*(2./(nx-1.))),u(:,i)
  ENDDO
  CLOSE(UNIT=200)
END PROGRAM odlc
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I am actually trying to get an output file containing nx lines and nt columns. Could suggest me how can I do that? @Simon

Comment: So a transpose matrix it seems, how can I do that? Many thanks in advance! @Simon

Comment: Then you have to store your results in an array of dimension `nt` by `nx` and do the writing at the end.

Comment: Exactly this is what I wanted and have been trying for over two months and failed! Finally, (1) how do I modify the fmt line <WRITE(fmt,*)'(',nt,'F5.2)'> to get <WRITE(200,fmt)REAL(i*(2/(nx-1))),u(:,i)>. This is to add a new column i*(2/nx-1) to my output file? (2) Can you pls suggest me good sources where I can find more about fortran format dealing with similar problems? Many thanks again!

Comment: (1) replace `WRITE(fmt,*)'(',nt,'F5.2)'` by `WRITE(fmt,*)'(I3,',nt,'F5.2)'` (2) I would just google *fortran90 formats*

Comment: Could you pls explain what first apostrophe in (',nt,'F5.2) is doing? Although I understand <F5.2> is assigning the decimal points but <'F5.2> is confusing me. Google was not helpful and hence my playing with inserting the first column of i*(2/nx-1) failed as replacing by I3 did not work. I highly appreciate your help.

Comment: I am writing into the string `fmt` in *free format* (`*`) a sequence of a string (`'('`), a number (`nt`) and another string (`'F5.2)'`). The apostrophe delimits the strings, that's it. Spaces may help to see things better: `WRITE(fmt,*)  '(I3,' , nt , 'F5.2)'`

Comment: Thank you so much for your patient answers!